# In magento 2 how to add custom data in sales order confirmation mail template

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email

In magento 2  how to add custom in data  sales order confirmation mail template

[image]

Comment: Custom data means? Any dynamic data or static data?

Comment: dynamic data from config setting

Comment: Amit bera solution will works perfectly...pls use that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to pass you to order using event `email_order_set_template_vars_before`.

Fire an observer on this event and this observer pass your parameter and  its value.

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer;

class OrderSender implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);

        $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getTransportObject();
        // new paremter
        $transportObject->setData('custom_field_1','value1');

    }
}
```

After that to show, you need to customization that order template from admin.

Check out the link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Then add `{{var custom_field_1}}` to print data at the email template.

Comment: its working good,  but i want to know by the above way  is there any chances to  get  a ordered product id or sku

Comment: i want to do some logic condition in observer to display a custom variable is there any chance to get a ordered product id or sku in above observer

Comment: I am getting NULL if i use $observer->getTransportObject() however, is working fine if I use $observer->getTransport(). Any idea ??